# Does the 7zip SFX or SevenZipSharp provide the in memory operation

Tags: c#, 7zip, sfx

I've investigated SFX components used in C#, I found Sevenzipsharp.dll may be a good chooice. But there are few dobuts in the 7zip beofre I go for it. Here are my questions:

1. Does Sevenzipsharp support in memory operating SFX .exe. For example, double click on the sfx exe, and one executable (maybe customized installer) inside the archive can be launched and operate the files in sfx exe in memory
2. Does Sevenzipsharp support creating a big sfx exe large than 4G (due to Windows limitation, maybe it can support to spilt an big data into one sfx exe linking with multiple big volume files, so double-click on the sfx exe, the all big volume files can be operate and extract in memory)

Comment: Why not ask in appropriate forum, https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to post the question there.